# Gmail attachment size limitation

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We're implementing emails sending with gmail api C# .NET Using the Google .net client library. We send emails containing large attachments with size more than 7 MegaBytes, and everything works good

```
var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
                                  {
                                      Body = message.Body,
                                      Subject = message.Subject
                                  };
foreach (var to in message.To) mailMessage.To.Add(to.Address);
foreach (var a in message.Attachments) mailMessage.Attachments.Add(a);

var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);

var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message { Raw = EncodeToBase64Url(mimeMessage.ToString()) };
await gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, "me").ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

What confuses us is attachment size as we can't find information about it's limitations. Also due to  Gmail documentation it has method "[Upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads)" to add attachments and we try to understand when we must use it instead of simple send like we do (please see the code above).

Comment: Gmail api documentation [Uploading Attachments](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads?hl=en)   Google.net client library [mediauploader](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload)

Comment: hi @DalmTo, thanks for the update, I've never met this link before.

Comment: However, the Gmail attachment size limit can be deceptive because Google encodes your email into a particular format before sending it.

This process can double the size of your attachment; thus, the actual Gmail attachment size limit is closer to 12.5 MB.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Total attachment size per Gmail message must be lower than 25MB.*

#### More Information:

From the documentation on [sending attachments with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20send%20up%20to,Google%20Drive%20attachment%20sharing%20settings.):

> You can send up to 25 MB in attachments. If you have more than one attachment, they can't add up to more than 25 MB.

As for upload methods:

- [Simple upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#simple) is designed for uploading small files, less than 5MB, when you can do the whole upload in one request.

```
POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: message/rfc822
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_file
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token

Email Message data
```

- [Multpart upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#multipart) is for when you want to send metadata along with the upload data, such as what thread the message belongs to or what labels the message should have.

```
POST /upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/send?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Email Message data
--foo_bar_baz--
```

The body of a multipart message should consist of a [users.messages.attachments resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments)

#### References:

- [Send attachments with yout Gmail message - Computer - Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20send%20up%20to,Google%20Drive%20attachment%20sharing%20settings.)
- [Uploading Attachments | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads)
- [REST Resource: users.messages.attachments | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments)

Comment: hi @Rafa Guillermo, could you please clarify when to use "Upload" method instead of simple send ? I.e. I'm adding the attachemnt to email of size more or less than 5 MB and simple "Send" method works good, without calling "Upload" method.

Comment: Basically, use simple if the file is to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails. It's literally the difference between sending the file in one go, or in parts - if you have a shaky connection then go with upload so that you don't have to upload the entire file each time.